# Are tablespaces associated with user accounts?

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have very basic question related to tablespaces.

When I was creating a user, I was asked to assign a default tablespace for this account. So, I assigned a previously created tablespace (TABLESPACE1).

If I create another user and assign a different tablespace (TABLESPACE2) for this user, then will I not be able to see tables created in TABLESPACE1?

If I create a user having access to both tablespaces (TABLESPACE1 and TABLESPACE2)
then for that user, there is another new database, but it is not actually new.

Could somebody help me to understand table space concept here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tablespaces are a storage concept only. They don't play a role in what user can see what tables.

You can set a default tablespace for a user, and you can allow them (or not) to create objects in specific tablespaces, but that is unrelated to what tables they have access to.

Table (and object in general) access is managed with grants. Tablespaces are for physical storage. The two are essentially unrelated.